# Reportable field in SugarCrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am newbie to SugarCrm

I need to know what is reportable field in sugarcrm and what it is used for?

Answer (score 3):

**Reportable Field**:

A field of any module which can be used to generate the reports and is visible on a report related to that module, such field is called reportable field.

**Reportable Field Types**

The following field types can be marked "Reportable":

```
Address     DateTime    Integer     Relate
--------------------------------------------
Checkbox    Decimal     MultiSelect TextArea
Currency    DropDown    Phone       TextField
Date        Float       Radio       URL
```

You can mark any field as reportable from the studio but such field should be made by a studio or should be listed in the studio.

You can set the field as reportable by the following steps:

- Navigate to Admin > Studio > {Module Name} > Fields.
- Select the field, you would like to have available in reports.
- Mark the checkbox for "Reportable" and click "Save".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Only *reportable* fields can be included in Reports, [all other fields will be unavailable](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Studio_and_Module_Builder/Troubleshooting_Fields_Not_Available_in_Reports/index.html).

Reports are a [module/feature of SugarCRM](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.8/Pro/Application_Guide/Reports/index.html) that allows you to receive information from SugarCRM based on a filter and a presentation that you can define yourself.

The information presented can have different shapes like e.g. plain data as simple lists, statistics as diagrams, summaries of the results of an e-mail campaign, etc.

You can then download the information as PDF document (or [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) or have it sent to you via mail (once or in an interval of your choice).

E.g. you could have

- a monthly report mailed to you that summarizes sales statistics for the CEO
- a weekly report that reminds marketing of existing customers that you haven't had contact with in over 6 months
- a daily report that sends marketing a list of newly acquired leads